# Simulating readout errors on aer simulator

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience, simulation

I'm trying to [simulate quantum experiments using a customized noise model](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.noise.ReadoutError.html#qiskit.providers.aer.noise.ReadoutError). Here's my code:

```
probabilities[0] = [0.9, 0.15]
probabilities[1] = [0.1, 0.85]
readout_noise_model = NoiseModel()
readout_noise_model.add_readout_error(probabilities[0], [0])
readout_noise_model.add_readout_error(probabilities[1], [0])
```

However, as I run the code, it returns me

```
--> 259         num_outcomes = len(probabilities[0])
    260         num_qubits = int(np.log2(num_outcomes))
    261         if 2**num_qubits != num_outcomes:

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

I don't know why this happens since I could find `len(probabilities[0])=2`. How can I set up the noise model for readout errors? Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: It might help if you could provide more of your code (ideally a minimal standalone example to reproduce the error). The error seems to be related to the object type of `probabilities` but your code doesn't show how that variable is declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the link that you provide in the first sentence of the question, you should write a single line

```
readout_noise_model.add_readout_error(probabilities, [0])
```

Comment: Thank you! That works!